# Put the transmission rate to 15Hz

Tags: android, ibeacon, ibeacon-android, android-ibeacon

Is it possible to set the transmission rate of a beacon to 15Hz with bluez ?I think the default rate is 1 Hz which is very low.

Comment: do you mean flashing bluez on a beacon?

Comment: I use a rapsberry pi with a bleutooth dongle and bluez to create a virtual beacon.

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use BlueZ to increase the transmission rate.  Check out my answer here on how to set it to 10 Hz:

[Is there a way to increase BLE advertisement frequency in BlueZ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124993/is-there-a-way-to-increase-ble-advertisement-frequency-in-bluez)

In my case, I was never able to make my dongle transmit more often than 10 Hz.  But that might be dongle-specific.  If the commands needed to set it to 15 Hz are:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 up
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0008 1e 02 01 1a 1a ff 4c 00 02 15 e2 c5 6d b5 df fb 48 d2 b0 60 d0 f5 a7 10 96 e0 00 00 00 00 c5 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x0006 78 00 78 00 03 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 07 00
sudo hcitool -i hci0 cmd 0x08 0x000a 01
```

If your bluetooth interface's max transmission rate is lower than 15 Hz,  the commands above will probably just end up setting it to the max rate.

Comment: Thank you, is it possible for me to identify my bluetooth interface's max transmission rate ?

Comment: I think it worked I am almost not detecting the beacon anymore, 2 detection in 10 scan period, It's probably transmitting too fast

Comment: I don't think you can find the max transmission rate without getting documentation for your chipset or trial and error.  It is possible to write code to count packets received per second on iOS, Android and OSX.