# Bluez example-advertisement interval linux

Tags: python, linux, bluez, ads

I am using Bluez 5.50 example-advertisement to work with a custom server that I edited from the example-gatt-server. It works just fine however I want to reduce the advertising interval i.e. increase the advertisement frequency.

Most help available online is using the hcitool for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21124993/is-there-a-way-to-increase-ble-advertisement-frequency-in-bluez).  I read the details about the advertisement packet and it should be possible to set the interval to a described vale as per the supplement to Bluetooth core specifications described [here](https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/bluetooth-core-specification). However, when I try to add it to the properties of the advertisement there is a parsing error. I am unsure how to go about this because of my unfamiliarity with python and dbus. 
I am attaching my code for the advertisement below. I added the set_advInterval section where it was needed along the code.

```
    `#!/usr/bin/python

    from __future__ import print_function

    import dbus
    import dbus.exceptions
    import dbus.mainloop.glib
    import dbus.service

    import array

    try:
      from gi.repository import GObject  # python3
    except ImportError:
      import gobject as GObject  # python2

    from random import randint

    mainloop = None

    BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME = 'org.bluez'
    LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisingManager1'
    DBUS_OM_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager'
    DBUS_PROP_IFACE = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties'

    LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE = 'org.bluez.LEAdvertisement1'


    class InvalidArgsException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
        _dbus_error_name = 'org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.InvalidArgs'


    class NotSupportedException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
        _dbus_error_name = 'org.bluez.Error.NotSupported'


    class NotPermittedException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
        _dbus_error_name = 'org.bluez.Error.NotPermitted'


    class InvalidValueLengthException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
        _dbus_error_name = 'org.bluez.Error.InvalidValueLength'


    class FailedException(dbus.exceptions.DBusException):
        _dbus_error_name = 'org.bluez.Error.Failed'


    class Advertisement(dbus.service.Object):
        PATH_BASE = '/org/bluez/example/advertisement'
    def __init__(self, bus, index, advertising_type):
        self.path = self.PATH_BASE + str(index)
        self.bus = bus
        self.ad_type = advertising_type
        self.service_uuids = None
        self.manufacturer_data = None
        self.solicit_uuids = None
        self.service_data = None
        self.local_name = None
        self.include_tx_power = None
        self.data = None
        self.advInterval=None
        dbus.service.Object.__init__(self, bus, self.path)

    def get_properties(self):
        properties = dict()
        properties['Type'] = self.ad_type
        if self.service_uuids is not None:
            properties['ServiceUUIDs'] = dbus.Array(self.service_uuids,
                                                    signature='s')
        if self.solicit_uuids is not None:
            properties['SolicitUUIDs'] = dbus.Array(self.solicit_uuids,
                                                    signature='s')
        if self.manufacturer_data is not None:
            properties['ManufacturerData'] = dbus.Dictionary(
                self.manufacturer_data, signature='qv')
        if self.service_data is not None:
            properties['ServiceData'] = dbus.Dictionary(self.service_data,
                                                        signature='sv')
        if self.local_name is not None:
            properties['LocalName'] = dbus.String(self.local_name)
        if self.include_tx_power is not None:
            properties['IncludeTxPower'] = dbus.Boolean(self.include_tx_power)
        if self.advInterval is not None:
            properties['Interval']=dbus.Uint16(self.advInterval)

        if self.data is not None:
            properties['Data'] = dbus.Dictionary(
                self.data, signature='yv')
        return {LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE: properties}

    def get_path(self):
        return dbus.ObjectPath(self.path)

    def set_advInterval(self,interval):
        self.advInterval=dbus.UInt16(interval)

    def add_service_uuid(self, uuid):
        if not self.service_uuids:
            self.service_uuids = []
        self.service_uuids.append(uuid)

    def add_solicit_uuid(self, uuid):
        if not self.solicit_uuids:
            self.solicit_uuids = []
        self.solicit_uuids.append(uuid)

    def add_manufacturer_data(self, manuf_code, data):
        if not self.manufacturer_data:
            self.manufacturer_data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature='qv')
        self.manufacturer_data[manuf_code] = dbus.Array(data, signature='y')

    def add_service_data(self, uuid, data):
        if not self.service_data:
            self.service_data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature='sv')
        self.service_data[uuid] = dbus.Array(data, signature='y')

    def add_local_name(self, name):
        if not self.local_name:
            self.local_name = ""
        self.local_name = dbus.String(name)

    def add_data(self, ad_type, data):
        if not self.data:
            self.data = dbus.Dictionary({}, signature='yv')
        self.data[ad_type] = dbus.Array(data, signature='y')

    @dbus.service.method(DBUS_PROP_IFACE,
                         in_signature='s',
                         out_signature='a{sv}')
    def GetAll(self, interface):
        print('GetAll')
        if interface != LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE:
            raise InvalidArgsException()
        print('returning props')
        return self.get_properties()[LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE]

    @dbus.service.method(LE_ADVERTISEMENT_IFACE,
                         in_signature='',
                         out_signature='')
    def Release(self):
        print('%s: Released!' % self.path)

    class TestAdvertisement(Advertisement):

        def __init__(self, bus, index):
            Advertisement.__init__(self, bus, index, 'per

ipheral')
        self.add_service_uuid('180F')
        self.add_manufacturer_data(0xffff, [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04])
        self.add_service_data('9999', [0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04])
        self.add_local_name('TestAdvertisement')
        self.set_advInterval(0.2)
        self.include_tx_power = True
        self.add_data(0x26, [0x01, 0x01, 0x00])


def register_ad_cb():
    print('Advertisement registered')


def register_ad_error_cb(error):
    print('Failed to register advertisement: ' + str(error))
    mainloop.quit()


def find_adapter(bus):
    remote_om = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, '/'),
                               DBUS_OM_IFACE)
    objects = remote_om.GetManagedObjects()

    for o, props in objects.items():
        if LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE in props:
            return o

    return None


def main():
    global mainloop

    dbus.mainloop.glib.DBusGMainLoop(set_as_default=True)

    bus = dbus.SystemBus()

    adapter = find_adapter(bus)
    if not adapter:
        print('LEAdvertisingManager1 interface not found')
        return

    adapter_props = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                                   "org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties");

    adapter_props.Set("org.bluez.Adapter1", "Powered", dbus.Boolean(1))

    ad_manager = dbus.Interface(bus.get_object(BLUEZ_SERVICE_NAME, adapter),
                                LE_ADVERTISING_MANAGER_IFACE)

    test_advertisement = TestAdvertisement(bus, 0)

    mainloop = GObject.MainLoop()

    ad_manager.RegisterAdvertisement(test_advertisement.get_path(), {},
                                     reply_handler=register_ad_cb,
                                     error_handler=register_ad_error_cb)

    mainloop.run()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
`
```

Answer (score 0):

According to https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/bluetooth/bluez/+/5.50/doc/advertising-api.txt the advertising interface api does not have property "Interval". Therefore we cant set the adv interval via this interface.